# Flutter/Dart: DateFormat (using intl): how to remove zero prefix?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-intl, dart-intl

I am using [`intl` pakage's `DateFormat`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) class to format dates with a format like this:

```dart
_standardDateFormat = DateFormat('MMM dd, yyyy');
```

This produces strings like `Feb 01, 2023`.

How can I have the date without the prefix of `0` when it's a single-digit date? I would like to show `Feb 1, 2023`. I have tried `d`, `dd`, `c` but they all render with the prefixed 0.

---

*If it's a double-digit date, I would of course like to show both digits: `Mar 13, 2023`*.

Comment: A single `d` should work (`DateFormat('MMM d, yyyy')`), and it works when I try it.  Can you double-check that it is not working for you?  If not, please post a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: I posted an update. It did work, but I needed to restart the build for some reason (not sure why)... Thanks!

Comment: If you mean that you didn't observe any change when doing a hot reload, then there are [a variety of reasons why hot reload might not include a change](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/hot-reload#special-cases).  It's hard to say why it didn't work in your case without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Update: the single `d` format is indeed working, but I needed to restart flutter build to see the effect (not sure why).